# Blocking read on GPIO from Python: How to block using epoll() and select.EPOLLET

Tags: python, select, embedded-linux, epoll, epollet

I'm experimenting with GPIO access from Python on an embedded system (ARM core), which is running linux built with Buildroot (kernel 4.1.15).

I want my code to BLOCK waiting for a pin change on GPIO2 (i.e. I don't want to poll the pin by calling "read" repeatedly). I'm trying to do this using "epoll" in edge-triggered mode:

See [Python docs for epoll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#epoll-objects). **select.EPOLLET** flag is used to get edge triggering for epoll. See also [Linux docs for epoll](https://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll).

For simplicity, I've already set up my GPIO pin from the console, using sysfs:

```
# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/direction 
in
# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/edge
rising
```

Here's my Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf8

from time import sleep
import select
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        pinIn = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value", "r")
    except IOError:
        print("Error setting up GPIO pin")
        sys.exit()

    myPoll = select.epoll()
    myPoll.register(pinIn.fileno(), select.EPOLLPRI | select.EPOLLET)

    while(1):

        events = myPoll.poll(4)
        print("EPoll result: %s" % (str(events),))

        for fd, event_type in events:
            print("FD: %d; Events: %d" % (fd, event_type))
            if event_type & select.EPOLLIN:
                print("-EPOLLIN!")
            if event_type & select.EPOLLPRI:
                print("-EPOLLPRI!")
            if event_type & select.EPOLLERR:
                print("-EPOLLERR!")

        value = pinIn.read(1)
        pinIn.seek(0)
        print("--> %s" % (str(value),))
        sleep(1)
```

For testing, I am feeding the input pin with a square wave from a signal generator at about 2 seconds per cycle, so I can see when the pin changes.

When I run this on my embedded system, I get this:

```
# python3 /usr/sbin/test-gpio-python.py 
EPoll result: [(3, 10)]
FD: 3; Events: 10
-EPOLLPRI!
-EPOLLERR!
--> 0
```

The code sleeps on the 1 seconds sleep, then on the next iteration, the poll() immediately returns and doesn't block. It should block since my input is only operating at one rising edge per 2 seconds.

**Why isn't "poll()" blocking?**

==== EDIT: ====

Originally, the code caused a weird error when I tried to use "select.EPOLLET":

```
OverflowError: can't convert negative value to unsigned int
```

However, I discovered that I had accidentally used **myPoll = select.poll()** instead of **epoll()**. Code now fixed.

Comment: I would recommend to consider use of *libgpiod* (in case you can use new kernel): https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/.

Comment: @0andriy Good info, thanks... I didn't know the sysfs interface is going to be deprecated! We are using kernel 4.1.15 at the moment though.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to check the interrupt information by looking at **/proc/interrupts**.

Here it is, only a couple of seconds after setting **edge** to "rising" for the GPIO pin:

```
# cat /proc/interrupts 
...
 33:        421  gpio-mxc   2 Edge      gpiolib
...
```

Hmm, 421 interrupts have occurred already!

Two seconds later:

```
# cat /proc/interrupts 
...
 33:        852  gpio-mxc   2 Edge      gpiolib
...
```

That could explain it. Interrupts are piling up at ~400 per second, definitely faster than I am processing them in Python.

Further investigation with a scope showed that the signal generator was only putting out about 1.6 V, and it looks like noise was triggering the input circuit on the device.

When I switched to the correct signal generator output and got a clean signal on the GPIO pin, I started getting the expected number of interrupts, and the python code worked correctly (i.e. poll() blocked correctly between rising edges on the input).

Comment: I'm still getting the "EPOLLERR" flag set along with "EPOLLPRI" in the event I get back when the poll() returns. However, it sounds like this might be normal behaviour... See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/quick2wire-users/ka-V_85ePtE